# How to add specific colors to data in JSON with d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, colors

I am trying to add more effect to a project for a hierarchical edge diagram on d3.js

This is based on the same hierarchical diagram as the one in mbostock (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999).

I want to assign specific colours when I mouse hover a link from my JavaScript to the JSON file. At the moment when you run it, it is automatically assigned in the stylesheet

For example:

JSON

```
[
{"name":"brand1","type:1","size":3938,"imports":["activity1"]}, colour assigned #8000ff
{"name":"brand2","type:2","size":3938,"imports":["activity2"]}, colour assigned #80bfff
{"name":"brand3","type:3","size":3938,"imports":["activity3"]}  colour assigned #66ffb3
]
```

In the JavaScript

```
var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node");

link = link
    .data(packageImports(root.leaves()))
    .enter().append("path")
      .each(function(d) { d.source = d[0], d.target = d[d.length - 1]; })
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", line);


function mouseovered(d) {
  node
      .each(function(n) { n.target = n.source = false; });

  link
      .classed("link--target", function(l) { if (l.target === d) return l.source.source = true; })
      .classed("link--source", function(l) { if (l.source === d) return l.target.target = true; })
    .filter(function(l) { return l.target === d || l.source === d; })
      .raise();

  node
      .classed("node--target", function(n) { return n.target; })
      .classed("node--source", function(n) { return n.source; });
}
```

I was thinking to add the following declaration

```
var fill = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(20))
    .range(["#eabe1d","#f7a51d","#e9962c","#ee7727","#f05620","#e82d24","#e91d26","#c62038","#ae1858","#1cbec9","#12aab5","#148ca5","#0a7887","#0a638b","#ec1559","#e61b4a","#b31c45","#a01b36","#651a5b"]);
```

But from there I don't how how to call it to search in the JSON the type1, type, type2 attribute.

Despite the JSON example as above the code was taken from mbostock.

Comment: Do you want to change the colour of all links or just the link hovered over?

Comment: Hi Gerardo, I have 20 colours to assign, for this example I want to change only specified links when they are hovered. tks

Comment: I am looking in the css, maybe this is the easiest way to do it but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around it seems to get the type in the JSON and to call it in the function.

```
[
{"name":"brand1","stroke": "#8000ff","size":3938,"imports":["activity1"]}, colour assigned #8000ff
{"name":"brand2","stroke": "#8680ff","size":3938,"imports":["activity2"]}, colour assigned #80bfff
{"name":"brand3","stroke": "#66ffb3","size":3938,"imports":["activity3"]}  colour assigned #66ffb3
]
```

then to call it in the link variable

```
link = link
    .data(packageImports(root.leaves()))
    .enter().append("path")
     .each(function(d) { d.source = d[0], d.target = d[d.length - 1]; })
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", line);
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.data.stroke; });
```

Though this is not working, links are getting mapped and build from the data to build the link, but the last line destruct all nodes.

Any thought how to avoid this?